# How much exp does a pet "steal"?

Tags: dark-age-of-camelot

If you have 8 people in the group (all with the same level, no pets), everyone gets exactly 1/8 of the experience points. Correct?

What happens if one player casts a pet (e.g. a Druid)?

Does this pet count as a 9th group member, so everyone would get only 1/9 of the total exp? (while the exp for the pet vanishes, of course)

Does it depend on activity of the pet, too? E.g. if the pet is passive or if it’s doing damage? What if it’s passive but heals the group? Is the pet level relevant? And is it working the same for charmed pets (e.g. by a Mentalist)?

Comment: It has been a while since I played this game, but I do remember that when the Bonedancer class was added you would get xp for anything killed by your pets no matter what, this resulted in people having a pet+healing pet and standing afk in blue/green spawn and leveling. So after this it was patched so you only get xp if there is also a player interaction. Sadly I do not know how this is divided and even if I could it would be outdated now, so I can't answer your question.